# Write a class SequenceCheck with a method sequenceCheck(int[] arr)

Tags: arrays

Use the array to print true if the elements 1,2,3 are present in the array. They need not be consecutive in the array. Print false otherwise...

Comment: does it matter what language this is in? please specify

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SequenceCheck{

 static void sequenceCheck(int arr[]){
     int c= 0;
   for( int i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
       if (arr[i]==1)
          c++;
       if (arr[i]==2)
          c++;
       if (arr[i]==3)
          c++;

  }

  if (c==3)
     System.out.println("true");
  else
     System.out.println("false");

}
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int array[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    sequenceCheck(array);
  }
}
```